# Button for smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling, scrollto

I am doing a button for smooth scrolling to the bottom of the page. The button is working, but without the smooth animation. Does someone have an idea, what I am doing wrong? The same kind of code for button to top is working fine. I need to do this without CSS "smooth".

```
document.getElementById("buttondown").onclick = function() {
  scrollTo(5555550, 2000);

}

// Element or Position to move + Time in ms (milliseconds)

function scrollTo(element, duration) {
  var rootelement = document.documentElement;
  if (rootelement.scrollTop === 0) {
    var up = rootelement.scrollTop;
    ++rootelement.scrollTop;
    rootelement = up + 1 === rootelement.scrollTop-- ? rootelement : document.body;
  }
  scrollToC(rootelement, rootelement.scrollTop, element, duration);
}

// Element to move, element or px from, element or px to, time in ms to animate 

function scrollToC(element, from, to, duration) {
  if (duration <= 0) return;
  if (typeof from === "object") from = from.offsetTop;
  if (typeof to === "object") to = to.offsetTop;

  scrollToX(element, from, to, 0, 1 / duration, 20, easeOutCuaic);
}

    
function scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion) {
  if (t01 < 0 || t01 > 1 || speed <= 0) {
    element.scrollTop = xTo;
    return;
  }
  element.scrollTop = xFrom - (xFrom - xTo) * motion(t01);
  t01 += speed * step;
  debugger;
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion);
  }, step);
}

function easeOutCuaic(t) {
  t--;
  return t * t * t + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add smooth behaviour to the function:

```
document.getElementById("buttondown").onclick = function() {
  window.scrollTo({
     top: 100,
     left: 100,
     behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kokodoko! But I have a problem with CSS behavior: 'smooth' that will not work on all browsers and need to do it with JavaScript.